# Eclipse Juno, maven 3.0.4, nexus, config

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I work, since severals months, on maven multi-module project. I have got 3 modules in this project : A, B and C.
Modules B and C have module A as dependency. All worked fine but my disk D: crashes : i have my os with eclipse, nexus on disk C: but the workspace and maven3.0.4 were on disk D: 
So i have reinstall maven on C:, i have now a new second disk (F:) where i want to reinstall the workspace by importing an older version saved, but the maven commands fail.
I suppose it's a problem with projects parameters in eclipse because the pom.xml files, setting.xml file , java sources, etc...were ok before this incident. I have updated M2_HOME with the new path, so what can it be ?

What i do : "clean install" for module A , OK !
The error message appears when i execute "clean install" via eclipse for module B : "Could not find artifact A:pom:0.1 in nexus". however module A jar and pom are well created in .m2 repository.

What i don't understand is all config worked fine before !!

When i read solutions about this problem, i have to change pom.xml...but all worked fine. So before to show my files, or change my sources, can it be just a parameters in eclipse to change ?
What could have changed ??

Comment: it seem's to be a plugin problems : when i run command "mvn clean install" from command line in module B repertory, it works !! but when i run it from eclipse, i get an error : access denied to /target/classes repertory (module A).......

Comment: and when i run from eclipse Maven-> Update project, i get : "Unsupported IClasspathEntry kind=4" , what does it mean ?

Comment: i try to update plugins but it doesn't work for m2e plugins

Comment: So, i desinstall eclipse juno, i have installed eclipse Luna that contains maven plugins, i replace my sources. When i run "clean install" (from eclipse) for module A, it works but when i run "clean install" for module B i get error message that says module A target/classes repository has a denied access...

Comment: I think i have  problem with maven config : when i click on Windows, preferences, Maven, Installations, i see 2 installations : EMBEDDED that is checked and the other is WORKSPACE but it's specified : NO AVAILABLE [3,0,). How to solve that ?

Comment: Why did you go forward two versions instead of to the *current* version?

Comment: certainly because i read more docs about maven/eclipse luna....but you're right i can install Eclipse Mars. i'm going to do it now

Comment: @nitind : OK it works with eclipse Mars :-) without changing my sources files !!